# GetDone in ibmmq (Node.js) doesn't stop listener of the queue

Tags: node.js, ibm-mq

I'm using ibmmq module https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs

I need to get message by CorrelId and then stop listen to the queue.

```
 async listen(queue: string, messageId?: string, waitInterval?: number) {
    let mqmd = new mq.MQMD()
    let gmo = new mq.MQGMO()
    gmo.Options = this.MQC.MQGMO_NO_SYNCPOINT | this.MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | this.MQC.MQGMO_CONVERT | this.MQC.MQGMO_NO_PROPERTIES | this.MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
    gmo.MatchOptions = this.MQC.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID
    mqmd.CorrelId = this.hexToBytes(messageId)
    gmo.WaitInterval = this.MQC.MQWI_UNLIMITED
    mq.Get(obj as mq.MQObject, mqmd, gmo, getCB)
  }
```

And the getCB function:

```
  getCB(err: mq.MQError, hObj: mq.MQObject, gmo: mq.MQGMO, mqmd: mq.MQMD, buf: Buffer, hConn: mq.MQQueueManager) {
    if (err) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
        console.log('GetDone:', hObj)
        mq.GetDone(hObj, err => {
          console.log('GetDoneError:', err)
        }) 
    }
  }
```

I start listening to the queue. Then I put a message with the CorrelId there. The listener get it. I see 'GetDone' in the terminal.
And then I put a message with the same CorrelId. And I get that message and Error.

```
GetDoneError: MQError: GetDone: MQCC = MQCC_FAILED [2] MQRC = MQRC_HOBJ_ERROR [2019]
    at Object.exports.GetDone (/home/apps/connector/node_modules/ibmmq/lib/mqi.js:2316:11)
    at MqiConnector.getCB (/home/apps/connector/src/wmq-mqi-connector.js:206:20)
    at /home/apps/connector/node_modules/ibmmq/lib/mqi.js:2263:14
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/apps/connector/node_modules/ffi-napi/lib/_foreign_function.js:115:9) {
  mqcc: 2,
  mqccstr: 'MQCC_FAILED',
  mqrc: 2019,
  mqrcstr: 'MQRC_HOBJ_ERROR',
  version: '1.0.0',
  verb: 'GetDone'
}
```

Looks like the loop with the function getCB didn't stop after GetDone.
I get messages with this CorrelId as many times as I send them. And every time I see this error. The listener is still running.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are calling `GetDone` twice and the second time `hObj` is invalid in the call to `mq.GetDone`.

```js
mq.GetDone(hObj, err => {
          console.log('GetDoneError:', err)
        })
```

I think you have fallen foul of Node.js asynchronous nature and you have hit a timing issue. IE. the cleanup following `GetDone` has not completed around the same time as the next message is being retrieved.

The function `GetDone` seems to be synchronous and can be found in https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs/blob/3a99e0bbbeb017cc5e8498a59c32967cbd2b27fe/lib/mqi.js

The error appears to come from this snippet in `GetDone` -

```
  var userContext = getUserContext(jsObject);
  var err;
  if (!userContext) {
    err = new MQError(MQC.MQCC_FAILED,MQC.MQRC_HOBJ_ERROR,"GetDone");
  } else {
    deleteUserContext(jsObject);
  }
```

First time through `userContext` is found and then deleted. Second time round `userContext` doesn't exist and the error is thrown.

The Sample in the repo - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs/blob/72fba926b7010a85ce2a2c6459d2e9c58fa066d7/samples/amqsgeta.js

only calls `GetDone` in an error condition, ie. when there are either no messages on the queue or there has been a problem getting the next message off the queue.

```
function getCB(err, hObj, gmo,md,buf, hConn ) {
   // If there is an error, prepare to exit by setting the ok flag to false.
   if (err) {
     if (err.mqrc == MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE) {
       console.log("No more messages available.");
     } else {
       console.log(formatErr(err));
       exitCode = 1;
     }
     ok = false;
     // We don't need any more messages delivered, so cause the
     // callback to be deleted after this one has completed.
     mq.GetDone(hObj);
   } else {
     if (md.Format=="MQSTR") {
       console.log("message <%s>", decoder.write(buf));
     } else {
       console.log("binary message: " + buf);
     }
  }
}
```

Whereas you are calling it when you have retrieved a message. You may need to create a guard that stops you calling it twice.

As for why the second message has been obtained, without an error, you might need to raise an issue on the ibmmq module.